# pandas ValueError: Cannot setitem on a Categorical with a new category, set the categories first

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Now, I am changing the information inside DataFrame by replacing Yes with 1 and No with 0. Previously, my code worked fine and now I made some changes due to a memory problem.

**Previous code** "Got Traceback Error mentioned below"

```
df.loc[df[df.decision == 'Yes'].index, 'decision'] = 1
df.loc[df[df.decision == 'No'].index, 'decision'] = 0
```

**Changed with**

```
df.loc['Yes', "decision"] = 1
df.loc['No', "decision"] = 0
```

Still, the problem remains the same.

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/226/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1477, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/226/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/khawar/deepface/tests/Ensemble-Face-Recognition.py", line 148, in <module>
    df.loc['Yes', "decision"] = 1
  File "/home/khawar/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 670, in __setitem__
    iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
  File "/home/khawar/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1763, in _setitem_with_indexer
    isetter(loc, value)
  File "/home/khawar/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1689, in isetter
    ser._mgr = ser._mgr.setitem(indexer=plane_indexer, value=v)
  File "/home/khawar/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 543, in setitem
    return self.apply("setitem", indexer=indexer, value=value)
  File "/home/khawar/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 409, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "/home/khawar/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 1688, in setitem
    self.values[indexer] = value
  File "/home/khawar/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/categorical.py", line 2011, in __setitem__
    "Cannot setitem on a Categorical with a new "
ValueError: Cannot setitem on a Categorical with a new category, set the categories first
python-BaseException
```

**As suggested I implemented new code**

```
df['decision'] = (df['decision'] == 'Yes').astype(int)
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/khawar/deepface/tests/Ensemble-Face-Recognition.py", line 174, in <module>
    gbm = lgb.train(params, lgb_train, num_boost_round=1000, early_stopping_rounds=15, valid_sets=lgb_test)
  File "/home/khawar/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lightgbm/engine.py", line 231, in train
    booster = Booster(params=params, train_set=train_set)
  File "/home/khawar/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py", line 2053, in __init__
    train_set.construct()
  File "/home/khawar/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py", line 1325, in construct
    categorical_feature=self.categorical_feature, params=self.params)
  File "/home/khawar/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py", line 1123, in _lazy_init
    self.__init_from_np2d(data, params_str, ref_dataset)
  File "/home/khawar/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py", line 1162, in __init_from_np2d
    data = np.array(mat.reshape(mat.size), dtype=np.float32)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'deepface/tests/dataset/029A33.JPG'
```

Comment: Could you try the following : `df['decision'] = (df['decision'] == 'Yes').astype(int)`. It should work for a binary categorical variable

Comment: I have written above line and now getting error about datatype conversion

Answer (score 12):

In your solution is problem there is `categorical` column, so if replace only some rows pandas want ouput column set to categoricals, and because `0,1` not exist in categories is raised error.

Sample data with categorical column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'decision':['Yes','No']})

df['decision'] = pd.Categorical(df['decision'])
```

Solutions with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`cat.rename_categories`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.rename_categories.html) for categorical ouput:

```
df['decision1'] = df['decision'].map({'Yes':1, 'No':0})
df['decision2'] = df['decision'].cat.rename_categories({'Yes':1, 'No':0})
```

If only `Yes` and `No` values is possible recreate all values by compare by `Yes` and cast to integer for `True, False` to `1,0` mapping like mentioned @arhr, categorical is lost:

```
df['decision3'] = (df['decision'] == 'Yes').astype(int)
print (df)
  decision decision1  decision2 decision3
0      Yes         1          1         1
1       No         0          0         0

print (df.dtypes)
decision     category
decision1    category
decision2    category  
decision3       int32
dtype: object
```

Comment: df['decision1'] = df['decision'].map({'Yes':1, 'No':0}) worked for me. I even didn't change the column name. df['decision'] = df['decision'].map({'Yes':1, 'No':0})

Answer (score 1):

I got the error while I tried to run whole model which contains different data types ("category" and "float64"). I solved the error just replacing "category" columns to "string" at the beginning, in this way:

```
for col in df.select_dtypes(include=['category']).columns:
  df[col] = df[col].astype('str')
```