# Is there a function in python for renaming values in one column based on the values in another?

Tags: python, annotations

Thanks in advance for the advice. I have a pandas dataframe. What I would like to do is label a column `(adata.obs['new_annotation]) as 'pDC'` when another column `(adata.obs['leiden_scVI'] == 10`.

It seems to me that loc is probably the best way to go about this. Therefore I have tried:

`adata.obs.loc[adata.obs['leiden_scVI']== '10', 'new_annotation'] = 'pDC'`

But this generates a value error:

> ValueError: Cannot setitem on a Categorical with a new category, set the categories first.

I've tried appending `.astype(category)` but this does not seem to solve the problem.

Is there another way of overcoming this please?

Many thanks.

ADDENDUM
Now solved - just need to change columns to .astype(str)

Comment: The problem seems related to the value itself, not to the approach, please share a minimal example to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks. By minimal example, do you just mean some of the dataframe? If so this is the adata.obs['leiden_scVI'].header(5)

AAACCTGAGACAGAGA-1-ad19     0
AAACCTGCAAGTTAAG-1-ad19     1
AAACCTGCAGGGTATG-1-ad19     1
AAACCTGCAGGTCTCG-1-ad19    10
AAACCTGGTACGAAAT-1-ad19    15
Name: leiden_scVI, dtype: category
Categories (20, object): ['0', '1', '2', '3', ..., '16', '17', '18', '19']

Then running:

adata.obs.loc[adata.obs['leiden_scVI']== '10', 'new_annotation'] = 'pDC'

Gives:

ValueError: Cannot setitem on a Categorical with a new category, set the categories first

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66100765/pandas-valueerror-cannot-setitem-on-a-categorical-with-a-new-category-set-the) it seem the same

Comment: Thanks very much for the advice