# Error while trying to replace multiple values of a pandas data-frame column based on matching condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in a pandas data frame, among other columns, as such:

```
     Remarks
   Left_only
  Right_only
   Left_only
  Right_only
```

For this column, I want to replace all `Left_only` values to `Yesterday` And `Right_only` To `Today`

I use this code line:

```
DF.loc[df[‘Remarks’] == ‘Left_only’, ‘Remarks’] = ‘Yesterday’
```

Similarly, for the other one. But I get this error:

```
Cannot setitem on a Categorical with a new category (Yesterday), set the categories first
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66100765/pandas-valueerror-cannot-setitem-on-a-categorical-with-a-new-category-set-the

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# create a dictionary to map the two values
d={'Left_only': 'Yesterday', 'Right_only':'Today'}
df['Remarks']=df['Remarks'].map(d)
df
```

```
0    Yesterday
1        Today
2    Yesterday
3        Today
Name: Remarks, dtype: object
```